# ng-disabled not working on IE

Tags: angularjs

I have the following radio input element where I am using ng-disabled to enable/ disable it based on a scope variable in my app controller. It  works perfectly on all browsers except IE 11. Can someone please tell me what I am missing / doing wrong here? I've researched the web but couldn't find any clue to what I might be doing wrong here. Thanks

```
 <input type="radio" id="select1" name="select1" value="{{payoption1}}" ng-model="order.payoption1" ng-disabled="clientDataloaded"/>
```

In controller:

```
 $scope.clientDataloaded = true; //this value change to false once client data is fully loaded...
```

Note: I am using Angular 1.2.6

Comment: What is the context where you assign clientDataloaded? You might need to call $scope.$apply() if it happens outside of an angular event.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of your IE (My IE 11.321.14393.0 on window 10)
I am trying to recreate your issue but cannot
Here is a live example which I tested all browsers and it works fine

you can update your IE or find another system with diffrent OS Win7/Win8.. for trying

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.clientDataloaded = true;
  }]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <button ng-click="clientDataloaded = !clientDataloaded">Enable/Disable</button>
    <input type="radio" id="select1" name="select1" value="{{payoption1}}" ng-model="order.payoption1" ng-disabled="clientDataloaded"/>
</div>
```